# What does this condition (s[i] && s[i] != c) means?

Tags: c, for-loop

```
#include <stdio.h>

char s[] = "`1234567890-=QWERTYUIOP[]\\ASDFGHJKL;'ZXCVBNM,./";

int main ()  
{
   int i, c;
   while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
      for (i = 1; s[i] && s[i] != c; i++);
      if (s[i]) putchar(s[i-1]);
      else putchar(c);
      /* code */
   }
   return 0;
}
```

Whats does the condition `s[i] && s[i] != c;` inside the for loop mean?
I haven't seen it before.
Thanks!

Comment: s is array, and i is the index :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all the variable `s` is a null terminated [C-string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2221304/why-do-strings-in-c-need-to-be-null-terminated), which is an array of chararcters with the last character being `'\0'`. You access that array with the index `i` in your code.
With that for loop you loop through the `s` string until a null terminator `'\0'` or the char `c` is found.
The null terminator `'\0'` is 0 decimal which means false in boolean logic because everthing else than 0 is true.

If you write for example:

```
char a = 'A';   /* same as char a = 65; */
if (a) { ... }; /* same as if (a != 0)  */
```

that means: `if a is true` which is: `if a is not false` and better: `if a is not equal to 0`. This statement will evaluate to true because `'A'` is 65 decimal ([ASCII code](http://www.asciitable.com/)) which is not equal to 0.

The for loop you've asked for can be rewritten as:

```
for (i = 1; s[i] != '\0' && s[i] != c; i++);
```

I would recommend to use explicit statements like `s[i] != '\0'` because it is easier to read.

Answer (score -3):

s[i] in if is going to check whether an element exists on s[i] . if element exists on s[i] then it's truthy if not then it's falsy .

c is being intialized with user input in while loop

```
c = getchar()



s[i] != c // it means that my inputted value can not be equal to s[i].
```

Comment: Your answer contains two false assertions : 
First, if a char `c` is assigned the value `'\0'`, i.e the null character, then `if(c)` would return false, and `c` would 'exist'(it is just `null`).
Second, it seems to me that trying to access a 'non-existing element' in C, such as out-of-bounds, results in undefined behavior. Most of time, the program would return false, but it still is UB, and thus shall never be considered reliable.