# Weird behavior with stack and heap while using strncpy

Tags: c, string, malloc, strncpy

I found a very interesting question.

When I'm using following code:

```
int main() {
    char * in = "hi, ";
    char str[10];
    strncpy(str, in, 2);
    printf("output = %s", str);
    return 0;
}
```

My result is nothing, the `printf` didn't work.

But if I use this:

```
int main() {
    char * in = "hi, ";
    char * str = malloc(sizeof(char) * 10) ;
    strncpy(str, in, 2);
    printf("output = %s", str);
    return 0;
}
```

I can get what I expect.

Why does this happen? Is it because of stack and heap? How exactly does that makes this huge difference?

Comment: what compiler error are you getting? The code seems correct

Comment: This code compiles just fine.  Are you sure that you didn't make some other typo?

Comment: Im using http://ideone.com/ to do the compiling which makes it says can't be compilied. I am still little bit confused and my computer did not have a gcc complier. Anyone can help me compile or give me a hand. Thanks so much.

Comment: oh, my bad. The way Im using stack will result a nothing comes out. The printf statement didnt work

Comment: man 3 strncpy ... BTW: threre are few case where you actually *need* strncpy(). This is not one of them.

Comment: Yes, this is actually a class excerise, I supposed to make strncpy function work and see how it work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The code compiles fine. The run-time error could be because, you haven't terminated the `str` with null.

From the man page:

> The strncpy() function is similar, except that at most n bytes of
>   src are copied.  Warning: If there is no null byte among the first n
>   bytes of src, the string placed in dest  will
>          not be null terminated.

Add `str[2]=0;` after the `strncpy()`.

Comment: the result I got is: http://ideone.com/2V0ZE#view_edit_box
it is working but can't print anything out. How so though???

Comment: It should be either `str[2]=0;` or `str[2]='\0';` double quote is for string literal.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I made so many mistakes. Should I delete this post? I fixed out.

Answer (score 6):

The problem - in **both** cases - is that your string won't be properly terminated after your call to `strncpy`.

You specify that `2` characters are copied, and your source string `in` has a length of 4. So `strncpy` will copy 2 characters, and since that is **less than** the length of the source string no null terminator will be added - to understand why this is so, review the [docs for strncpy](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strncpy):

`If count is reached before the entire string src was copied, the resulting character array is not null-terminated.`

In this case you'll want:

```
str[2] = '\0';
```

after the 'strncpy'.

The second case may **seem** to work because the buffer that you get from `malloc` happens to be initialized to all zeros, but you **shouldn't** rely on this.

Please review the [docs for strncpy](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strncpy), noting the exception for null termination, and in general, be careful with string termination!

For even more detail see: [Why are strings in C++ usually terminated with '\0'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10943033/why-are-strings-in-c-usually-terminated-with-0/10943040#10943040)

Comment: I think he'll want str[2] = 0, not str[3] = 0

Comment: Well, it still like before, it complies but nothing comes out.

Answer (score 1):

You could initializing the memory with zeros to be on the "safe" side.

Have a look at the following code,

```
int main() {
    char * in = "hi, ";
    char str[10]={0};    
    strncpy(str, in, 2);
    printf("output = %s", str);
    return 0;
}

int main() {
    char * in = "hi, ";
    char * str = calloc(10,sizeof(char));
    strncpy(str, in, 2);
    printf("output = %s", str);
    free(str);      //<<Important step
    return 0;
}
```

`str[2] = '\0';` is also a valid solution.

Comment: Thanks for helping, actually, my biggest mistake is that I did double qouted instead of single quote on second edition. Stupid mistake I made causes this XD