# char pointer initialization in C

Tags: c, string, pointers, char

I am not so clear on character pointer and how they work.

The program builds, but crashes when I run it.

```
 char *ab = NULL;
 //ab = "abc123"; // works fine
 sprintf(ab, "abc%d", 123); // this line seems to crash the program
```

I don't get how this can be wrong, when sprintf takes in a (char * str) as a first argument.

Can anyone please explain this to me?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You have allocated no memory to use with `ab`.

The first assignment works because you are assigning to `ab` a string constant: `"abc123"`. Memory for constant strings are provided by the compiler on your behalf: you don't need to allocate this memory.

Before you can use `ab` with e.g. `sprintf`, you'll need to allocate some memory using `malloc`, and assign that space to `ab`:

```
ab = malloc(sizeof(char) * (NUM_CHARS + 1));
```

Then your `sprintf` will work so long as you've made enough space using `malloc`. Note: the `+ 1` is for the [null terminator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10943033/why-are-strings-in-c-usually-terminated-with-0/10943040#10943040).

Alternately you can make some memory for `ab` by declaring it as an array:

```
char ab[NUM_CHARS + 1];
```

Without allocating memory somehow for `ab`, the `sprintf` call will try to write to `NULL`, which is undefined behavior; this is the cause of your crash.

Comment: `sizeof(char)` is guaranteed to be `1` (not to be confused with `CHAR_BITS`) so it's not necessary.  You should also mention that you need to allocate space for the trailing `'\0'`.

Answer (score 2):

You need to allocate memory for your data. Indeed `sprintf` takes `char*`, but it doesn't allocate memory for you.

The first line works fine because compiler automatically allocates data for constant tables of chars defined at compile time.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this

```
char ab[10];  //allocate memory
sprintf(ab, "abc%d", 123);
```

Answer (score 1):

Unlike in `Java` or other higher level languages, many of the `C` library's string functions don't simply set a string reference, instead they operate on a block of pre-allocated memory called a character array.

Your first line is saying that `ab` points to a non-existent memory location.

You'd have more luck if, instead of `char *ab = NULL;` you did either:

```
char ab[12];
```

or:

```
char *ab = (char*)malloc(12);
```

Answer (score 0):

"ab" is null and sprintf is trying to write to it, you have to allocate it first.

```
char ab[20];

sprintf(ab, "abc%d", 123); //
```

or

```
char * ab = malloc(20); // new, whatever

sprintf(ab, "abc%d", 123); //
```

Comment: `new, whatever` is kind of useless, since it's C, not C++

Answer (score 0):

There are several things to think about here. Your original example is below:

```
char *ab = NULL;
 //ab = "abc123"; // works fine
 sprintf(ab, "abc%d", 123); // this line seems to crash the program
```

`char *ab = NULL;` is a pointer to a character and is initialized to NULL;

I don't think `ab = "abc123";` worked fine unless it looked like `char *ab = "abc123";`. That is because you initialized `char *ab` to a read-only string. The initialization probably took place at compile time.

Your `sprintf(ab, "abc%d", 123);` line failed, because you did not initialize any memory for the `char *ab` pointer ahead of time. In other words, you did not do something like:

```
ab = malloc((sizeof(char) * 3) + 1); /* + 1 allows for null string terminator. */
```

You can fix your problem one of two ways. Either allocate dynamic memory as shown above, or you can make the string an array of a fixed length, like char `ab[25] = {0};`. Usually, I create an array of a length like 1024, 256, or some number that will usually cover most of my string length cases. Then I use char pointers for functions that operate on the array.