# Printing character array in C

Tags: c, arrays, memory, data-segment

I know I am supposed to put '/o' at end of character array but
When I want to print "printf ("%s\n", kk);" , it gives "abcdepqrst". Why is this happening?
This is the program I am executing.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{

char kk[]={'a','b','c','d','e'};
char s[]="pqrst";

printf("%s\n",s);

printf("%s\n",kk);

}
```

**Output:**

pqrst

abcdepqrst

I tried reversing the order in which I declare the array by declaring array 's' before array 'kk' here, [ideone link](http://ideone.com/j9DaJY), but I am still getting the same output. I think it has something do with how ideone allocates memory to variables.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
char s[]="pqrst";
char kk[]={'a','b','c','d','e'};


printf("%s\n",s);

printf("%s\n",kk);

}
```

**Output:**

pqrst

abcdepqrst

Comment: Also see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10943033/why-are-strings-in-c-usually-terminated-with-0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `printf()` function expects a null terminated string but you are passing a character array with no null terminator. Try changing your array to:

```
char kk[]={'a','b','c','d','e','\0'};
```

When you use string literal syntax to initialize your `s` array, the null terminator is automatically added:

```
char s[] = "pqrst"; // s is {'p','q','r','s','t','\0'}
```

Comment: Please check the edit.

Comment: What's the point of all of these downvotes?

Comment: @EugeneSh.; Beware of ghost souls!!

Comment: Is the behaviour undefined as said by @juanchopanza.

Comment: @c0de222 yes, it is undefined behaviour, typically you will just see whatever is in memory after your non-terminated string until there happens to be a 0 byte or you cause an access violation. In your case it happens the compiler has chosen to place your other string `s` immediately after `kk` in memory.

Answer (score 4):

`kk` is not null-terminated, so `printf` doesn't know where to stop. Invoking `printf` on a string that is not null-terminated is *undefined behaviour* (UB). That means you cannot expect any particular outcome from your program. What you see is one manifestation of UB.

You need to add a null-terminator:

```
char kk[]={'a','b','c','d','e', '\0'};
```

Comment: Okay. So we can not expect a particular output?

Comment: @c0de222 Right, UB means pretty much anything can happen.

Comment: But practically, it will just print everything in the memory starting at `kk` until the first zero is encountered. Which in your case at the end of `s`. And as the `s` and `kk` are allocated on stack, it is going "backwards".

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a '\0' character to kk as it's last element like so:

```
char kk[]={'a','b','c','d','e','\0'};
```

or printf is just going to run off the end of the array.

Comment: Please check the edit.

Comment: I commented on your question with a link to an answer which clears the concept.

Comment: Thanks for the link.