# Using '\0' as a comparison operand

Tags: c++, arrays

My function should list all the elements of the char array on the screen. But it should stop if the array is finished. The size of the arrays are variable. I thought that the array is terminated by '\0'. So I did this:

```
for(int i=0; i< size; i++){
    if(word[i] != '\0')
        cout<< word[i];
}
```

But the program doesn't stop there. It creates some random symbol.

E.g. char number[]= "0123"
     The program gives: 0123§&

What is wrong with my if-condition?

Comment: you need to `break`, e.g. stop after seeing `\0`.

Comment: If this is truly C++ then use of `std::string` is strongly advised. You're walking off the end of the array here if you get garbage like that.

Comment: I'm just leaving this link here. https://stackoverflow.com/a/10943040/5132337

Comment: Why do you use size instead of testing ‚\0‘

Comment: Using the [debugger](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging/) would have quickly unfolded what the problem is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that your code won't stop when it encounters `'\0'`, it just doesnt print the `'\0'` and continues on.

Try changing your for loop condition

```
for(int i=0; word[i] != '\0'; i++){
    cout<< word[i];
}
```

And if you just want to just print it, a simple

```
cout<<word;
```

would have sufficed

Comment: Nice use of loop limits instead of an `if` statement.

Comment: @lucau glad that it helped. If you are learning c++ then do look into `std::string` as suggested by the others, it will be much more useful than character arrays