# why below code is giving garbage value?

Tags: c, string

why following code is giving garbage value ?
    here I am trying to get an string as an input from user character by character. In the following code i have got input from user and stored in string[] array then in order to do some other operations i have stored the same in other array called temp_string[i]. But surprisingly i am getting garbage value in output.and also length calculated using `strlen` is not correct. can anybody look at this code and explain whats going wrong?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdio.h>

int main()    
{
    char ch;
    int i = 0, j = 0;
    int length = 0;
    int lengthsb = 0;
    char string[100];

    printf(" Enter the string to divide\n "); 
    while(ch != '\n')
    {
        ch = getchar();
        string[i] = ch;
        i++;
    }
    char temp_string[i];
    printf("%s", string);
    i = 0;
    while(string[i] != '\n')
    {
        temp_string[i] = string[i];
        i++;
    }

    length = strlen(temp_string);
    printf("Entered string is  %s and its length is %d\n", temp_string, length);
}
```

Comment: `string` is not NUL-terminated (`'\0'`).

Comment: nor is `temp_string`

Comment: Thank you I got the answer for my query :)

Answer (score 3):

You forgot to add the null at the end of the string.
C strings are null-terminated, that means that all operations in c strings expect a null to mark the end of the string, including functions like strlen.

you can achieve that just adding:

```
string[i] = '\0';
```

After fill the string.

Another thing, what happens if the user enters a string bigger than 100? Is good to validate the input for these cases, otherwise you can get a buffer overflow.

Comment: Thank you I got the answer for my query :)

Answer (score 2):

You need to add a NULL - terminated at the end of your string. Add `\0`.

Answer (score 2):

You need to put a `'\0'` char at the end of the string so `strlen()`, `printf()` and other C functions dealing with strings will work. That is how the C API knows it reached the end of the string.

Also, you don't want to set new characters at the memory space **past** the string array. So you better check that in your loop (and save a last array item to set the `'\0'`).

```
while (ch != '\n' && i < 99)
{
  ch = getchar();
  string[i] = ch;
  i++;
}
string[i] = '\0'; // set the string terminator past the end of the input
```

Remember to do the same after copying the characters to `temp_string`. (By the way, you can replace that loop with a call to [strcpy()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcpy/), that does exactly that, **except** it will end only when it finds a `'\0'`.)

You might also want to read [What's the rationale for null terminated strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4418708/whats-the-rationale-for-null-terminated-strings)

Comment: Thank you I got the answer for my query :)

Comment: Please, accept the question (click the check) that helped you.

Answer (score -1):

Here is your Final Code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

int main()
{ 
char ch;
int i = 0, j = 0;
int length = 0;
int lengthsb = 0;
char string[100];
char temp_string[100];

printf(" Enter the string to divide\n ");
while(ch != '\n')
{
ch = getchar();
string[i] = ch;
i++;
}
string[i]=NULL;

printf("%s", string);
i = 0;
while(string[i] != '\0')
{
temp_string[i] = string[i];
i++;
}
temp_string[i]=NULL;

length = strlen(temp_string);
printf("Entered string is  %s and its length is %d\n", temp_string, length);
}
```

In the above code what exactly you are missing is NULL or '\0' termination of the string. I just added it to make it useful.

Comment: Thank you I got the answer for my query :)

Comment: `NULL` is a pointer - you should not be assigning it to a `char` - use `'\0'` for the string terminator character.