# Something I don't get about C strings

Tags: c, string, pointers

A few questions regarding C strings:

1. both `char*` and `char[]` are pointers?
2. I've learned about pointers and I can tell that `char*` is a pointer, but why is it automatically a string and not just a char pointer that points to 1 char; why can it hold strings?
3. Why, unlike other pointers, when you assign a new value to the `char*` pointer you are actually allocating new space in memory to store the new value and, unlike other pointers, you just replace the value stored in the memory address the pointer is pointing at?

Comment: I'm sure most of your questions have been asked before in this site. Search for them and see what you still don't understand.

Comment: You may find [**this question**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4418708/whats-the-rationale-for-null-terminated-strings) an interesting read.

Comment: Start with the link from WhozCraig above, but it is fairly apparent you need to revisit **pointers** and **string literals** again in a C reference. All of your questions are fairly simple questions related to pointers. **Do not** shortcut your learning/understanding about pointers in C - they provide the basis for most of the advanced language capabilities of C and they provide a quagmire for those that only **sortof** understand them.

Comment: Succinctly: (1) No, but they often both behave like pointers, except when the array doesn't behave like a pointer; (2) a `char *` doesn't automatically point to a string — a string is a null-terminated string of characters, and not everything that a `char *` points at is a null-terminated string of characters; and besides, an `int *` can point at either a single `int` or at the start of an array of `int` and you can't tell the difference; (3) I can't make head or tail of your third question.

Comment: Take a look at the [comp.lang.c FAQ](http://www.c-faq.com/).

Comment: You need to understand that neither C strings nor C arrays are in any sense "real".  Any address can be cast to `char*` and the bytes it addresses can then be declared (by the programmer) to be a "string", whether it makes sense or not.  (And assigning something to a pointer, `char*` or not, doesn't cause bytes to be allocated.  A `char*` is no different from a `int*` or a `double*` in that regard.)

Answer (score 3):

A pointer is not a string.
A string is a constant object having type `array of char` and, also, it has the property that the last element of the array is the null character `'\0'` which, in turn, is an `int` value (converted to `char` type) having the integer value `0`.

1. `char*` is a pointer, but `char[]` is not. The type `char[]` is not a "real" type, but an **incomplete type**. The **C** language is specified in such a way that, in the moment that you define a concrete variable (object) having array of char type, the size of the array is well determined in some way or another. Thus, none variable has type `char[]` because this is not a type (for a given object).

   However, automatically every object having type `array of N objects of type char` is promoted to `char *`, that is, a **pointer to char** pointing to the initial object of the array.

   On the other hand, this promotion is not always performed. For example, the operator `sizeof()` will give different results for `char*` than for `an array of N chars`. In the former case, the size of a `pointer to char` is given (which is in general the same amount for every pointer...), and in the last case gives you the value *N*, that is, the size of the array.

   The behaviour is differente when you declare function arguments as `char*` and `char[]`. Since the function cannot know the size of the array, you can think of both declarations as equivalent.
2. Actually, you are right here: `char *` is a pointer to just 1 character object. However, it can be used to access strings, as I will explain you now: In the paragraph **1.** I showed you that the strings are considered objects in memory having type `array of N chars` for some `N`. This value N is big enough to allow an ending null character (as all "string" is supposed to be in **C**).

   So, what's the deal here?

   The key point to understand this issues is the concept of **object (in memory)**.
   When you have a **string** or, more generally, an **array of char**, this means that you have figured out some manner to hold an array object in memory.
   This object determines a portion of RAM memory that you can access safely, because **C** has assigned enough memory for it.
   Thus, when you point to the first byte of this object with a `char*` variable, actually you have guaranteed access to all the adjacent elements to the "right" of that memory place, because those places are well defined by **C** as having the bytes of the array above.

   Briefly: the adjacent (to the right) bytes of the byte pointed by a `char*` variable can be accessed, they are valid places to access, so the pointer can be "iterated" to walk through these bytes, up to the end of the string, without "risks", since all the bytes in an array are contiguous well defined positions in memory.
3. This is a complicated question, but it reveals that you are not understanding the relationship between pointers, arrays, and string literals in **C**.

   - A pointer is just a variable pointing to a position in memory.
   - A pòinter to char points to just 1 object having type char.
   - If the adjacent bytes of the pointed position correspond to an array of chars, they will be accessible by the pointer, so the pointer can "walk on" the memory bytes occupied by the array object.
   - A string literal is considered as an array of char object, which implictely add an ending byte with value 0 (the null character).

   In any case, an **array of T** object has a well defined "size".
   A **string literal** has an additional property: it's a constant object.
   Try to fit and gather these concepts in your mind to figure out what's going on.

   And ask me for clarification.

**ADDITIONAL REMARKS:**

Consider the following piece of code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
   char *s1  = "not modifiable";
   char s2[] = "modifiable";
   printf("%s ---- %s\n\n", s1, s2);
   printf("Size of array s2: %d\n\n", (int)sizeof(s2));

   s2[1] = '0', s2[3] = s2[5] = '1', s2[4] = '7',
   s2[6] = '4', s2[7] = '8', s2[9] = '3';
   printf("New value of s2: %s\n\n",s2);
   //s1[0] = 'X';   // Attempting to modify s1
}
```

In the definition and initialization of `s1` we have the string literal `"not modifiable"`, which has constant content and constant address. Its address is assigned to the pointer `s1` as initialization.
Any attempt to modify the bytes of the string will give some kind of error, because the array content is read-only.

In the definition and initialization of `s2`, we have the string literal `"modifiable"`, which has, again, constant content and constant address. However, what happens now is that, as part of the initialization, the content of the string is **copied** to the array of char `s2`. The size of the array `s2` is not specified (the declaration `char s2[]` gives an incomplete type), but after initialization the size of the array is well determined and defined as the exact size of the copied string (plus 1 character used to hold the **null** character, or end-of-string mark).

So, the string literal `"modifiable"` is used to initialize the bytes of the array `s2`, which is modifiable.
The right manner to do that is by changing a character at the time.
For more handy ways of modifying and assigning strings, it has to be used the standard header `<string.h>`.

Comment: About answer 2, so it can store Strings because the length of the String is constant after defining it and I can read it safely without accessing different memory ? Also this applies to other pointer data types like int ? Can I use int pointer to point to an int array because it'll be safe to read because the array size is defined and memory is allocated for this array so I could read it safely ?

Comment: About answer number 3, I /think/ I might have an idea why it allocates new memory each time you write value to where the pointer points at and assign this value to the new place in memory. This is because Strings size in memory can differ from one another unlike other data types where they have constant size in memory and it won't change ? And if we were to change the value in the original adress the pointer pointed it'll cause some problems ?

Comment: Every string literal defines a constant (read-only-memory) array of chars. This array has an address. This address is assigned to the pointer. The adjacent adressess are accessible, because they form a contiguous block of memory holding the bytes of the array. This block of memory is safe for reading. This property applies for any type of array. "Allocated" objects are obtained with `malloc()`, but it's the same: they determine contiguous blocks of memory safe for reading.

Comment: Don't think about "string size", but better about "array objects in memory". The size is determined by the block of contiguous elements in the array object. What allows you to access safely a block of memory is the fact that this block is previously allocated for an array. Every array has a constant address, but their bytes are variable. However, a string literal is not variable: their bytes cannot be modified. If you change the address to what your pointer is pointing, then you are pointing to anything else.

Comment: If you say: `char *p; p = "stringy 1";` and then `p = "stringy 2"`, this **doesn't mean at all** that the string "stringy 1" is overwritten (in place, in the same memory address) by "stringy 2". What is really happening is that "stringy 1" and "stringy 2" are different arrays with different addressess, and p points first to the former, and then to the last one.

Comment: and if I were to do *p = "stringy 2" ? it will modify the array in the first address the pointer pointed at or will it allocate new memory for the "stringy 2" char array ?

Comment: The first array "stringy 1" will not be modified nor its address. Thus, new memory is allocated to hold the array of char: "stringy 2", whose address is assigned to `p`. Actually, your assignment is wrong, because `*p` is not pointer to char, but the char (pointed by `p`).

Comment: I have added an example and its corresponding explanation to my answer. I think it could show differences between the use of `char*` and `char[]` for strings.

Answer (score 1):

1. `char *s` is a pointer, `char s[]` is an array of characters. Ex.

   ```
   char *s = "hello";
   char c[] = "world";
   s = c; //Legal
   c = address of some other string //Illegal
   ```
2. `char *s` is not a string; it points to an address. Ex

   ```
   char c[] = "hello";
   char *s = &c[3];
   ```
3. Assigning a pointer is not creating memory; you are pointing to memory. Ex.

   ```
   char *s = "hello";
   ```

   In this example when you type "hello" you are creating special memory to hold the string "hello" but that has nothing to do with the pointer, the pointer simply points to that spot.

Comment: "char s[] is an array of characters" Unless it's in a function parameter list, in which case it *is* a pointer.