# NUL char in strings in C++

Tags: c++, string, c++11

In the below code I am trying to replace the first character with `'\0'`.

I expected it to print an empty string, but in the output it just omits that and displays the rest of the characters.

```
int main()
{
    string str;
    cin >> str;

    str[0] = '\0';

    cout << str << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

**OUTPUT :**

```
   testing
   esting
```

How do I terminate the string in C++?

PS: I was trying this approach of terminating the string in a different question in which I need to terminate in between.

Comment: NULL is a `#define` for a Null-pointer in the language `C`. It is sometimes used as pointer value in `C++` too, but this is not consensus. But NULL is never a character constant.

Comment: If you try `str.c_str()` it might give the output you want, but I don't recommend using strings this way.

Comment: Be very careful when try to manipulate the internals of `std::string`. The memory is generally laid out in a contiguous fashion (IIRC because of the requirements of `std::string.c_str()` but you should not assume too much about how the container (`std::string`) manipulates and uses that memory. It is ill-advised to attempt to manipulate the raw contents without the container's knowledge. Use the `std::string()` methods where necessary, there are many, and the standard algorithms where required; they will work well together.

Comment: @Niall You can't manipulate the internals of `std::string` in general, but you can modify specific characters by indexing into the string, as he has done, or by dereferencing a valid iterator, and there are also a number of non-const member functions which permit explicit manipulations.

Comment: @JamesKanze Correct, the manipulation above is via the member `operator[]`

Comment: The `NUL` character is not omitted by `cout`, the `NUL` character is written to `stdout`. The terminal receives the `NUL` character and ignore it.

Comment: @Niall: C++11 requires `std::string` to be contiguous. But even in C++03, it's totally acceptable to do what the OP is doing. You can modify any character in the string (i.e. `str[i] = anyChar` for any `0 ≤ i < str.size()`) without "breaking" the string at all. FWIW, `operator[]` *is* a method in `std::string` intentionally added so people can do things like this.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

`std::string` is not a null terminated string. If you want to empty it use the `clear()` method. If you want to remove an element of the string use the `erase()` method.

Comment: @Niall It is, in fact, guaranteed not to be implemented as a null terminated character array, since it's perfectly legal for an `std::string` to contain a `'\0'`.

Comment: @JamesKanze Correct, did we not say the same thing?

Comment: @Niall your "is not guaranteed" statement allows for it to be possible that `std::string` is implemented as null-terminated, just not guaranteed as such. James' "is guaranteed not" statement allows only for non–null-terminated implementations, which is correct.

Comment: @Niall You said "is not guaranteed", I said that it was actually forbidden.

Comment: @JamesKanze Do you have reference for that in the specification, where is it forbidden to be implemented like that? I thought the implementation was free to layout the memory backing a string as it requires. I agree it may contain '\0' my comment was talking to the fact that you should make no assumptions about how it is laid out in memory.

Comment: @Niall The fact that you can put a `'\0'` in a string means that the implementation cannot use it as a sentinel.  (C++11 does require that the memory be contiguous, and that `c_str()` return the same thing as `&str[0]`, but that still doesn't allow the implementation to treat `'\0'` as a terminator.)

Comment: @JamesKanze Correct. I agree, the `'\0'` mustn't be used as a sentinel. It if for these very reason that C++ `std::string` must not be thought of as a C-style character array. My apologies if we were talking past each other, or the confusion from my first comment.

Comment: @Niall: You seem to confuse "char array" and "null-terminated string".  A null-terminated string is a char array of which only the last char is null \0. As `std::string` must be able to hold any char array, it can't be restricted to the subset of null-terminated strings.

Comment: @JamesKanze Technically you could still use `\0` as a sentinel and only switch to a different internal representation when the user tries to insert a `\0` character. It doesn't really make much sense to do it, since it would only make the implementation more complex and less efficient due to the overhead of checking for `\0` in every operation, but it's still possible.

Answer (score 35):

There are two approaches to strings.

In C, strings are zero-terminated, meaning the '\0' indicates the end of the string, which is what you are expected.

C++ (and most languages) uses counted strings, meaning the end of the string is indexed, so adding null terminators to the string won't terminate it.  '\0' is a non-printing character, so when you print, you get the behavior you see.  If you want to manipulate std::string length, you need to use the std::string methods (http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/).

**C++ doesn't care about null terminators for strings.  They are just used for C compatibility.**

Incidentally, this should have the behavior you were expecting.

```
cout<<str.c_str()<<"\n";
```

See also

[Why null-terminated strings? Or: null-terminated vs. characters + length storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1253291/why-null-terminated-strings-or-null-terminated-vs-characters-length-storage)

[What's the rationale for null terminated strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4418708/whats-the-rationale-for-null-terminated-strings)

Comment: +1, though "C++ uses length prefixed strings" - not literally "prefixed" (as in say Borland Pascal) - if there's a length data member at all it will almost certainly be a separate data member from the pointer-to-dynamically-allocated-characters, and not overlaid with the first few bytes thereof, though with short string optimisation it could coincidentally sometimes be a prefixed in terms of memory layout.  Other string implementations could store a pointer to the end of the data rather than a size.

Comment: I was really hung up on how to describe C++'s style of string storage and fell back on what I had read about pascal once upon a time.  What's a better term for the general practice of indexing the last character?

Comment: I always knew them as "counted strings".

Comment: Not sure how to say it concisely :-/.  I'd tend to say something like "std::string has a size member, separate from the textual data, so it doesn't need a sentinel to mark the end."

Answer (score 14):

You just think you got

```
testing
esting
```

as output, but you actually got

```
testing
 esting
^
|
+-- "empty" \0 char
```

because the `std::string` still has the length of "testing", you just replaced the first character 't' with '\0'. When `std::cout` gets the string, it looks at the string *length* and outputs all its characters, which makes the '\0' cause an "empty" slot in the output.

To really clear the string, prefer to call `std::string::clear()`. Also valid is `std::string::reset(0)`, but it's not as expressive (you can even assign an empty string... shudder). The implementation may or may not use a '\0' at all, so don't think of that as a way to fiddle with the externally observed representation.

Answer (score 10):

A `std::string` resembles pretty much the functionality of a `std::vector`. If you want to erase all the elements of your `std::string` you could use `std::string::clear`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() {
  std::string str("testing");
  std::cout << str << std::endl;
  str.clear();
  std::cout << str << std::endl;
}
```

If you want to delete a particular character from your string (e.g., the 1st charater) you could use `std::string::erase`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() {
  std::string str("testing");
  std::cout << str << std::endl;
  str.erase(str.begin());
  std::cout << str << std::endl;
}
```

If you want to remove particular characters from your string you could, as in the case of `std::vector`, use the erase-remove idiom:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

int main() {
  std::string str("testing");
  std::cout << str << std::endl;
  str.erase(std::remove_if(str.begin(), str.end(), [](char const &c){ return c == 't'; }), str.end());
  std::cout << str << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

According to the std::string implementation, the [] return the reference for the character in given position in the internal char array. When you set as str[8]= ‘\0’ it sets. You can check it by calling str.c_str() function. It return the internal array.

However, 
The cout reads it characters without null chars in the middle. It is the reason for the output.

```
const_reference operator[](size_type __n) const
{
    return *(_M_start + __n);
}

reference operator[](size_type __n)
{
    return *(_M_start + __n);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

To get string that ends on first character you need to first extract `char const*` from `string` by calling method `string::c_str()`. Then it will be processed as you wish (like in C).

Answer (score 3):

Maybe use the good old printf like `printf("%s", str.c_str());` this will print it out C style, and should terminate on the null character. things like `strlen(str.c_str());` should work as well. What I suspect is that since C++ strings have a .size() function somewhere it probably has a `int size;` member, they don't waste any time checking for a null character every time they want to print. They can probably just say to print str.size() characters.